# Test fails on a null pointer exception when I use @InjectMocks

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit4

I am practising restful api endpoints using https://api.predic8.de/shop/docs

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/ciaranmckenna/spring5-mvc-rest/blob/master/src/test/java/guru/springfamework/services/VendorServiceTest.java)

I am getting a NPE failure when I try to use @InjectMocks during my TDD approach

However, I can make my test pass when I make a direct call in the `setup()`

```
vendorService = new VendorServiceImpl(VendorMapper.INSTANCE, vendorRepository);
```

I wanted to extend my learning by trying to create an endpoint for getting all vendors.

When I employ TDD along the way, but, my test `getAllVendors()` fails on a NPE when I try to use `@InjectMocks` but passes when I substitute it for a direct call in the `setup()` method.

The NPE is linked to the mapper class I think.

Here are the classes that I believe are useful. VendorServiceTest, VendorServiceImpl, VendorMapper.

I have commented out the direct call in the setup as I want to get the test passing using `@InjectMocks`

> package guru.springfamework.services;
>
> import guru.springfamework.api.v1.mapper.VendorMapper; import
> guru.springfamework.api.v1.model.VendorDTO; import
> guru.springfamework.domain.Vendor; import
> guru.springfamework.repositories.VendorRepository; import
> org.junit.Before; import org.junit.Test; import
> org.mockito.InjectMocks; import org.mockito.Mock; import
> org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations; import
> org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
>
> import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List;
>
> import static org.junit.Assert.*; import static
> org.mockito.Mockito.when;
>
> public class VendorServiceTest {

```
public static final String NAME = "Tasty";
public static final Long ID = 1L;

@Mock
VendorMapper vendorMapper;

@Mock
VendorRepository vendorRepository;

@InjectMocks
VendorServiceImpl vendorService;

//VendorService vendorService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    //vendorService = new VendorServiceImpl(VendorMapper.INSTANCE, vendorRepository);
}

@Test
public void getAllVendors() {
    //given
    List<Vendor> vendors = Arrays.asList(new Vendor(), new Vendor(), new Vendor());

    when(vendorRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(vendors);

    //when
    List<VendorDTO> vendorDTOList = vendorService.getAllVendors();

    //then
    assertEquals(3, vendorDTOList.size());
}

@Test
public void findByName() {
}
```

}

> package guru.springfamework.services;
>
> import guru.springfamework.api.v1.mapper.VendorMapper; import
> guru.springfamework.api.v1.model.VendorDTO; import
> guru.springfamework.repositories.VendorRepository; import
> org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
>
> import java.util.List; import java.util.stream.Collectors;
>
> @Service public class VendorServiceImpl implements VendorService {

```
private final VendorMapper vendorMapper;
private final VendorRepository vendorRepository;

public VendorServiceImpl(VendorMapper vendorMapper, VendorRepository vendorRepository) {
    this.vendorMapper = vendorMapper;
    this.vendorRepository = vendorRepository;
}

@Override
public List<VendorDTO> getAllVendors() {
    return vendorRepository
            .findAll()
            .stream()
            .map(vendor -> {
                VendorDTO vendorDTO = vendorMapper.vendorToVendorDTO(vendor);
                vendorDTO.setVendorUrl("/api/v1/vendors/" + vendor.getId());
                return vendorDTO;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public VendorDTO findByName(String name) {
    return vendorMapper.vendorToVendorDTO(vendorRepository.findByName(name));
}

@Override
public VendorDTO getVendorById(Long id) {
    return vendorMapper.vendorToVendorDTO(vendorRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new));
}
```

}

> package guru.springfamework.api.v1.mapper;
>
> import guru.springfamework.api.v1.model.VendorDTO; import
> guru.springfamework.domain.Vendor; import org.mapstruct.Mapper; import
> org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;
>
> @Mapper public interface VendorMapper {

```
VendorMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(VendorMapper.class);

VendorDTO vendorToVendorDTO(Vendor vendor);
```

}

Does anyone know where and why I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you created mock object for the mapper, but you didn't say what should happen when the method `vendorToVendorDTO` is called.
Therefore, when that method is called in the next line of code:

```
VendorDTO vendorDTO = vendorMapper.vendorToVendorDTO(vendor);
```

It will return null, and then in this line of code:

```
vendorDTO.setVendorUrl("/api/v1/vendors/" + vendor.getId());
```

You will get `NullPointerException`.

To make this work, change your `getAllVendors()` method as follows:

```
  @Test
    public void getAllVendors() {
        //given
        List<Vendor> vendors = Arrays.asList(new Vendor(), new Vendor(), new Vendor());
        VendorDTO mockDto = mock(VendorDTO.class);
        when(vendorRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(vendors);
        when(vendorMapper.vendorToVendorDTO(any(Vendor.class))).thenReturn(mockDto);
        //when
        List<VendorDTO> vendorDTOList = vendorService.getAllVendors();

        //then
        assertEquals(3, vendorDTOList.size());
    }
```

And the test should pass.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`/`@ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class)` over your test class?

Comment: When I do I no longer get a failure on the `getAllVendors()` within the `VendorService` however, the assertion fails as the `vendorDTOList.size()` , which I guess is due to a NPE as well only further down the code path.

Comment: This NPE is because your mocked `mapper` returns null. You could fix this with `when(mapper. vendorToVendorDTO(vendors)).thenCallRealMethod()`.

Comment: `@Test
    public void getAllVendors() {
        //given
        List<Vendor> vendors = Arrays.asList(new Vendor(), new Vendor(), new Vendor());

        when(vendorRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(vendors);
        when(vendorMapper.vendorToVendorDTO(any(Vendor.class))).thenCallRealMethod();

        //when
        List<VendorDTO> vendorDTOList = vendorService.getAllVendors();

        //then
        assertEquals(3, vendorDTOList.size());
    }`
It fails.

Can't call abstract real method on java object
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.

Comment: Appologises about the formatting, I didnt have the option to format a code block and command and k didn't format for me.

Comment: Ok, so I suggest you to use constructor injection instead of `@InjectMocks`:  `vendorRepository` can remain annotated with `@Mock` and `mapper` is `VendorMapper.INSTANCE`.